# The PDE $u_t = -\Delta^2 u -\Delta u + f$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, applications

Does the PDE $u_t = -\Delta^2 u -\Delta u + f$ have a physical use or meaning? I am asking specifically about the the Laplace term after the biLaplace term.. is it unusual or "unnecessary" in some way to have both terms at the same time?

Thank you

Comment: In the stationary case $u_t=0$ you can find a lot of information (physical interpretation for example) in this book: http://www.amazon.com/Polyharmonic-Boundary-Value-Problems-Mathematics/dp/3642122442/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1356369525&sr=8-1&keywords=polyharmonic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the linearization of th [Cahn-Hilliard equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Hilliard_equation) about a constant state. The equation is used to model phase separation in binary mixtures and alloys. The quantity $u$ then is a volume fraction.